# BOOL inside of NSMutableArray gives wrong answer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray that contains a BOOL.  Elements are added via:

```
addObject:@[@YES, sectionInfo.header, myFeedSource.header
```

I then walk thru the array as follows:

```
    for (int i=0; i<revealController.headersSelected.count; i++) {
        isActive = [revealController.headersSelected[i][0] boolValue];
        MLog(@"Active %@",revealController.headersSelected[i][0]);
        MLog(@"class %@",[revealController.headersSelected[i][0] class]);
        MLog(@"converted %d",[revealController.headersSelected[i][0] boolValue]);
        if (isActive) {
            MLog(@"Yes");
        }else {
            MLog(@"No");
        }
        if (revealController.headersSelected[i][0]) {
            MLog(@"Yes");
        }else {
            MLog(@"No");
        }
        if (revealController.headersSelected[i][0]>0) {
            MLog(@"Yes");
        }else {
            MLog(@"No");
        }
```

The output is:

```
Active 0
class __NSCFBoolean
converted 0
No
Yes
Yes
```

The only way I can get it to see the correct value of the sub-element is to convert it into a var with:

```
        isActive = [revealController.headersSelected[i][0] boolValue];
```

The value of this BOOL is set inside of the For..Next loop via *replaceObjectAtIndex:*

What am I missing here?  Why doesn't it see the correct value of the BOOL?

I've printed out the whole array before and after, the value changes from 1 to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments on your output:

```
Active 0              This is truth
class __NSCFBoolean   This is truth
converted 0           This is truth
No                    This is truth
Yes      This is a lie, because you're testing for pointer existence
Yes      This is a lie, because you're testing the pointer isn't a zero
```

So, I'd guess you're editing something which is a copy sometimes and not updating it back into your data structure, and / or you need to be careful with unpacking the `NSNumber` instances.

Comment: It isn't 'a lie', the output is correct based on the comparison being performed.  The comparison just isn't doing what the OP *thinks/wants it to do* - which you have explained

Comment: Fair point, it's the printing as YES which is misleading rather than a lie strictly

Answer (score 1):

You can only store objects in an `NSArray`, not intrinsic types like BOOL.  `@YES` is a shorthand way of saying `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` - i.e. you are creating an NSNumber object with the required boolean value.

NSNumber is a class cluster, so it picks the appropriate subclass to store your value.  In this case it is an `NSCFBoolean`.  In order to access the boolean value you need to use the `boolValue` method as you have shown.

Comment: ok, so why doesn't the '>0' work?  Is it not an NSNumber because of the @YES?  Ok, wait.  I was checking a pointer to an object being >0.  Looks like I have to convert no matter what.

Comment: that's correct.  @Wain explains in his answer what you are actually doing